# Wanted to make textarea with text editor set to required but won't work

Tags: php, html, textarea, text-editor

I created a simple page with textarea with condition that it should be required when the textarea is empty.

```
<div class="control-group hidden-phone">
  <label class="control-label" for="textarea2"></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea class="cleditor" id="textarea2" rows="3" name="isi_visimisi" required><?php echo $data['isi_visimisi'] ?></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I press submit button with condition that the textarea is empty, it doesn't show any alert that the textarea need to be filled

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I 'm a beginner in coding so please help :)

Comment: tried moving the php code to placeholder and value but still won't working

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654454/form-validation-in-php

Comment: "don't work" **HOW**?

Comment: If I press submit button without data in the textarea it doesnt prompt the alert that it's not filled yet. Sorry my English is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started:

```js
$('textarea').blur(function(){
  if (this.value.length) $(this).removeAttr('required');
  else $(this).attr('required', 'required');
});

$('button').click(function(){
  var attr = $('textarea').attr('required');
  if (typeof attr == 'undefined' && attr !== false) alert('No required attribute');
  else alert('Textarea has required attribute');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="control-group hidden-phone">
  <label class="control-label" for="textarea2"></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea class="cleditor" id="textarea2" rows="3" name="isi_visimisi" >Default text in field</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<button>TEST: Does textarea have required attribute?</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it now see if I can make it work in my code

Answer (score 1):

If it has any content, including whitespace, it will pass the check.  Is $data['isi_visimisi'] a string with any length at all?

Also, you must have a submit button for this to work.  If you're submitting the form via JavaScript or some other means, the HTML5 required keyword won't work.

Comment: Yes the string has length. The idea is that the text in the textarea can be changed but not empty. And yes I have submit button.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using CLEditor.  The editor set the initial textarea as hidden and provides its own html to build the text editor. When you submit your form, the alert is attached to your hidden textarea, so you can't see it.

Comment: Is there a way to make the alert visible ?

Comment: You just need to modify the css of your textarea when your editor is initialized. Check out the DOM and make the modification you need. You need to make it visible, even if it's a 0px width.